# Why am I getting an undesired output in my Array Queue program?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

The program is an Array Based Queue I am attempting to program.
The puzzling output I am getting is:

*Enqueuing 500

4199136 500*

I cannot figure out why **4199136** is outputting, after the space in the *Output* function.

I know it is some sort of memory/array management issue I am making, but I can find the flaw. Any insight would be much appreciated.

The code is posted below in its entirety.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#define MAX_SIZE 10

using namespace std;

class ABQ
{
    private:
        int a[MAX_SIZE];
        int count, front, back;
    public:

    ABQ()
    {
            front = -1;
            back  = -1;
            count = 0;
    }

    bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return(front == -1 && back == -1);
    }

    bool IsFull()
    {
        return (back + 1) % MAX_SIZE == front ? true : false;
    }

    void Enqueue(int n)
    {
        cout << "Enqueuing " << n << endl;

        if(IsFull())
        {
            cout << "Array Based Queue is FULL" << endl;
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            back = (back + 1) % MAX_SIZE;
        }

        a[back] = n;
    }

    void Dequeue()
    {
        if(IsEmpty())
        {
            cout << "Array Based Queue is EMPTY" << endl;
            return;
        }

        else if(front == back)
        {
            back = front = -1;
        }

        else
        {
            front = (front + 1) % MAX_SIZE;
        }
    }

    int Front()
    {
        if(front == -1)
        {
            {
                return -1;
            }
            return a[front];
        }

        return 0;

    }

    void Output()
    {
        count = (back + MAX_SIZE - front) % MAX_SIZE + 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            int index = (front + i) % MAX_SIZE;
            cout << a[index] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
       ABQ Q;
       Q.Enqueue(500);
       Q.Output();


       return 0;
}
```

Comment: Output is different for me, try it [here](http://cpp.sh/9x236).

Comment: @Mark That's odd, still not sure why I get the '0' before the 500 when ran 'here'. Any insight into that? (I am using Eclipse C++/C to compile my code)

Comment: Try printing out the value of `index` as well as `a[index]` and you will see one thing that is wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's partly because your initial values for `front` and `back` are out of range for your array indexes, and partly because you don't handle `front` correctly.

After the call to `Enqueue(500)`, `front` will still be `-1` and `back` will be `0`.  When you call `Output`, this will output two values, one at `a[-1]`, which is Undefined Behavior, and the other at `a[0]`.

Your `Output` function (and possibly other places) needs to not consider the value at `a[front]` as a valid element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in `count = (back + MAX_SIZE - front) % MAX_SIZE + 1;` statement.

Note that after `Q.Enqueue(500);` the value of back = 0 and front = -1.

Hence `count` will be calculated as (0 + 10 - (-1)) % 10 + 1 =  2.

Now you can understand that count is wrong after first `Enqueue`.